# Вопрос по библиотеке Jsoup(скопировать элементы и вставить)

Tags: java, android, jsoup

Работаю с библиотекой Jsoup, такой вопрос, имеется html страница c таким содержанием, например:

```
<div class="newclass">
  <div class="newclass2">
     <div id="nt">...</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Как скопировать  и вставить в newclass, то есть, чтобы получилось вот так:

```
<div class="newclass">
   <div id="nt">...</div>
</div>
```

спасибо.

Answer (score 1):

```
Как-то так)

Element element = doc.getElementById("nt");
doc.select("div.newclass2").remove();
doc.select("newclass").append("<div id=\"nt\">" + element.html() + "</div>");
```